# Rotating marker in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, markers

I am creating markers using this method :

```
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset);
`enter code here`markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,0),icon));
```

Now , I want to rotate the marker 90 degrees to the left (or right).

How can I do it?

I was able to find example to rotate a feature , but I am not using a feature.
Instead, I am using a marker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dariapra mentioned. Your better off using a vector feature so you can take advantage of the `rotation` property.

You will find no drawbacks from switching over. You will see that using  the more flexible feature vector will be more convenient.

Use the [`externalGraphic` style property](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html#style-properties) to designate the marker image.

Answer (score 0):

I think this boils down to how you can rotate the marker image using JavaScript as I don't think there's a way of using OpenLayers to do this.

There's a neat CSS3 way of rotating images here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp. And there's plenty of JavaScript libraries that will do this for you...you might find you're using a library (e.g. JQuery) that has this capability for you already.

One last thing. Rotating images can sometimes look a bit messy when done on the fly so the other alternative is to display your features as a vector - though whether this works for you will depend what your icon looks like and whether you can get a decent vector representation of it.